# Show that the following language is not context free by using the pumping lemma

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Let B be the language of all palindromes over $\{0,1\}$ containing equal number of 0s and 1s. Show that B is not context free.

Attempt: I plan to show the string $0^p1^p1^p0^p$ can't be pumped. But the problem is that if we pick v= x 1s and y= x 1s then $uv^ixy^iz \in B$ for any $i$ except for $i=0$. My question is, when we choose a word, do we have to show it can't be pumped in any way? or we have to show that for each case (in this case v and y just contain 1's), there exists a way it can't be pumped?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pumping lemma says:

> **There is** a pumping length $p$ such that **for every** sufficiently long word in the language **there is** a qualifying decomposition of that word such that **for every** $n$, this decomposition pumped $n$ times in in the language.

When you want to prove that $B$ is *not* context free, you need to argue that the pumping lemma property is *false* for $B$, so you have to *negate* the description above. This produces

> **For every** pumping length $p$ **there is** a (sufficiently long) word in the language such that **for every** qualifying decomposition of that word **there is** an $n$ such that the decomposition can **not** be pumped $n$ times.

which is what you have to prove.

In order to prove such a multiply-quantified claim *you* get to choose everything marked up with "there is", whereas *your enemy* chooses things marked up with "for every" and you have to be prepared to response no matter what he comes up with.

Thus,

- First the enemy chooses a $p$.
- Then you choose a word $w$ of at least $p$ symbols.
- *The enemy* decides how to split your word as $w=uvxyz$, following the rules of the lemma.
- After seeing this decomposition you must give an $n$, such that ...
- $uv^nxy^nz$ is not in the language.

So you don't get to choose how to split $0^p1^{2p}0^p$ into five parts. You have to argue that *no matter how this splitting is done* (as long as $|vxy|\le p$, etc), it will not be pumpable.

Comment: So when you say "no matter how this splitting is done", you are implying I have to cover all possible ways the splitting can be done in order to contradict the claim.

Comment: @daniel: Not really "implying": It's what I'm saying straight out.